# How can I check error code inside foreach loop?

Tags: powershell, foreach

I need to make a simple script for DB logical dump. The goal to use the script for two purposes.

1. If I run it with parameter (DB names) it shall create a logical dump of those DBs.
2. If I run without parameters it starts command for a list of DBs (hardcoded).

I want to check error code for each command start (`pg_dump`) inside `foreach` loop, log it and continue.
What's the best way to do it?

So far I dicovered that I can use `try` and `catch`.

Side-note: In my code I tried `try..catch` only once for testing purposes.

```cs
$path = '"C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\version\bin\pg_dump.exe"'
$backup_path = 'D:\Backups\test\'
$limit = (Get-Date).AddDays(-2)
$logdate = (Get-Date).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
$pg_suffix = "pg_dump"
#$LogFile = $backup_path\$pg_suffix_$(Get-Date -f yyyy-MM-dd) + '.log'
$pg_dump_error = "pg_dump has failed"

$p = $args
[array]$DB_Array = @('postgres', 'db02', 'db03')

if ($p -ne $null) {
    try {
        foreach ($DB in $p) { 
            $backup_path_temp = $backup_path + $DB + '_' + $(Get-Date -f yyyy-MM-dd) + '.backup'
            cmd /c "$path -w -h localhost -U postgres -Z3 -Fd -j 12 -f $backup_path_temp $DB" 
        }
    } catch { 
        #"Error! $pg_dump_error" | Tee-Object -FilePath $LogFile -Append | Write-Error }
        Write "Error: $file.name: $_" >>D:\\Backups\logfile.txt
    }
    continue;
} else {
    foreach ($DB in $DB_Array) {
        $backup_path_temp = $backup_path + $DB + '_' + $(Get-Date -f yyyy-MM-dd) + '.backup'
        cmd /c "$path -w -h localhost -U postgres -Z3 -Fd -j 12 -f $backup_path_temp $DB"
    }
}
# Delete files older than the $limit.
Get-ChildItem -Path $backup_path -Force |
    Where-Object { !$_.PSIsContainer -and $_.CreationTime -lt $limit } |
    Remove-Item -Force -Recurse
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `$LastExitcode` automatic variable for getting the exit code of a executable in PowerShell.